# Apex 3.2 Button to call javascript

Tags: oracle-apex

When I create a new button, I select, Create a button displayed among this region's items, and finish the button wizard and have a new button.

I am looking to uncheck a checkbox after a page is submitted when a specific button is clicked.  When a user clicks on the 'Submit' button, I want the 'Tick All' check box to be unchecked after the page submits.

[image]

```
How do I call a javascript function using this type of button?  
Does it go in the Button Display Attributes - Attributes section?  
  If so, can you  supply a syntax example?
Does it go into the Button Request Value - Button Request section?
  If so, can you supply a syntax sample?
Does it go in the Post Element Text?
  If so, can you supply a syntax example?
```

I know that if I select, "Create a button in a region position", I add "javascript:..." in the URL portion.

Comment: "I want the 'Tick All' check box to be unchecked after the page submits" -> the page has to be submitted (ie values saved to session state) and then the checkbox has to be unchecked? When is this? On the page reload or somewhere in your page processing after-submit?

Comment: @TOM The user click on the checkbox, makes a selection from the select list, then clicks on the 'Submit' button to apply the select list item.  While the page is submitted, I would like for the checkbox to be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an after-submit process of type 'Clear **Cache for Items (ITEM, ITEM, ITEM)**', and specify your checkbox in it.
Checking the checkbox, making a selection and then submitting the page implies that you want to process this selection made but do not want to have the checkbox retain its saved session state (ie having been checked). By clearing its cache you will reset it to the default state.
If 3.2 has no such process, you could use a plsql process or computation to set the value of the checkbox to 0 or null (whichever value is the default value).